# Inverse exclusion script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

I'm wondering if anyone can help me with a problem I'm having.

I'm trying to create an exclusion script for an automated journey. I have another another data extension with a list of people I wish to use in the exclusion script.

However I want to do the inverse of an exclusion list and only send the email to **subscribers from the entry audience who were matched in the other data extension.**

So if a subscriber exists within the entry audience data extension as well as the other data extension, the email should send.

Does anyone know if this is possible and have an idea of what the script should look like?

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to send to subscribers have a match in the other data extension, then the exclusion script should select those that don't have a match:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DataExtensionNameGoesHere", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) == 0
```