# How to find email address available or not in the multiple data extension journey builder exclusion script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, exclusion-script

How to check in exclusion script if  the Email address is in the multiple data extension should be send the email else do not send the email in journey builder email summery.

```
IF(AND(EmailAddress IS IN TestDE1, Emailentrydate = Today()), Send Email, Do not Send Email)
OR
IF(AND(EmailAddress IS IN TestDE2, Emailentrydate = Today()), Send Email, Do not Send Email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have several conditions in your Exclusion Script with the only main rule that it should end up with `'True'` or `'False'` result. In your case, it would look somewhat like that -

```
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension_1", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) > 0
AND
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension_2", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) == 0)
OR
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension_1", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) == 0
AND
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Data_Extension_2", "EmailAddress", emailaddr)) > 0)
```

Lastly, before creating a condition, review the [LookupRows AMPscript function guideline](https://ampscript.guide/lookuprows/) to create correct filtering criteria.
And check out answers to those questions:

1. [Exclusion Script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/111394/99298)
2. [Inverse exclusion script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/195344/99298)
3. [Exclusion Script with time](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/261088/99298)

Hope it helps.